# Android: GridView opens the same entry (the first clicked one) in subsequent clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I apologize upfront if the question is too long. Here we go:

`MainActivity:` The activity that hosts the `GridView` which has the list of products,

`ProductDetailActivity:` The activity that shows the details of the selected item in `GridView` after the click,

`ProductMainAdapter:` The adapter class for product data in `GridView`.

```
The workflow:
```

1 - The user opens the app, main activity starts (`launchMode="singleTask"`), with a list of products queried from server using `Volley`, and listed in a `GridView`. The queried data include productIDs and images only.

2 - User clicks on any product (item) on `GridView` and the selected productID is used to get detailed information from server (`Volley`) and opening the `ProductDetailActivity` with the intent that has selected product data.

3 - User sees the details and turns back to `MainActivity` and selects another item. And goes on like that.

This workflow works perfectly in %95 of users` devices. But every once in a while I get a message from a user which in summary says: "The first clicked product keeps opening in subsequent clicks". For example, user clicks on item X, and the details of X opens. Then user goes to main and clicks on item Y, but item X is opening again. I tested it in emulator with all the available Android versions from 15 to 25 over the past few weeks. I also tested it with all the devices that I can find around me, but could not reproduce the issue. A user sent a video showing the problem and it is a genuine issue.

The relevant code snippet in the `Adapter` is as follows:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
...

holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openProductDetail(position);
            }
        });
...
}

private void openProductDetail(int position) {

    if(!Connectivity.isConnected(getContext())) {
        CommonUtil.buildDialog(getContext(), getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_title),
                getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_msg)).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        ImageRecord imr = getItem(position);
        String productID = imr != null ? imr.getId() : "0";
        getProductDetail(productID);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("openProductDetail", "exception", e);
    }
}

private void getProductDetail(final String productID) {

        ...

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.PRODUCT_DETAIL_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            if(response != null && !response.equals("")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid", productID);
                                intent.putExtra("jsonObject", response);

                                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", productID);
                ...
                return params;
            }
        };

        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(1000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(getContext()).getRequestQueue().add(postRequest);
    }
```

And the ProductDetailActivity code is:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ...

        productID = getIntent().getStringExtra("pid");
        jsonObject = getIntent().getStringExtra("jsonObject");

...
}
```

Since I am not able to reproduce the issue, I could not debug it. I could have asked a user to give me their phone for testing, they live in another country.

Either `GridView` is caching the first click and keeps returning it, or the product detail activity cashes its data for some reason. I tried using `onItemClickListener()` of `GridView` but did not work. I also tried sending only the productID to the detail activity and Volleying the details from the new activity. That did not work either. Have anyone ever faced a similar situation? Any suggestion or comment is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: [view reusing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) + async calls = boo(out of sync problems) ... also what happend with dialog when you rotate the screen?

Comment: @Selvin : The screen orientation is Portrait, so nothing happens when rotating (I hope I understood your question right). Which view am I reusing here? Thanks!

Comment: @Selvin, It turns out that the problem does not occur in Wi Fi or 4G LTE but occurs in 3G Network connection.

Comment: @erolyeniaras you have mentioned that you tried sending the pid to detail activity and fetched the data through network call. Is the network call results in error and is it returning back the old (first pid) valule? Also if its error, can you brief a bit on the error..

Comment: Turns out, some devices caches the selection when the network is bad or memory is limited. Setting No History in the intent solved the issue. Thanks!