# Volley works on WIFI but not on 3G

Tags: java, android, android-activity, gridview, android-volley

I apologize upfront if the question is too long. Here we go:

There are two activities: `Main` and `Detail` Activity.

`Main Activity` is basically a GridView. 
`Detail Activity` is basically shows the clicked item's detail information. I am passing selected item's id (`pid`) from the `Main` to the `Detail` Activity.

I am facing an issue as follows. Initially, I have `3G` connection (cellular connection) and clicked on the first item and see the corresponding item detail in the `Detail Activity`, it works perfectly fine, and go back to the `Main Activity`, then clicked on the second item, then unfortunately it still shows me the first item in the `DetailActivity` that I clicked initially.

I switched from `3g` to `wifi` while app is on the active and open. No matter what I click, it still shows me the first item that I clicked initially.

But when I delete the app and reinstall it and get either `wifi` access **only**, the app works perfectly fine.

In the following implementation, Connection URL (PRODUCT_DETAIL_URL) is `http`, not `https`. I am using `Volley` library for the network connection.

**DetailActivity.java**

```
private void productDetailInit() {
      // it is http
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.PRODUCT_DETAIL_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                jsonObject = response;
                                loadJsonData();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", productID);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(1000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().add(postRequest);
    }
```

**CustomVolleyRequest.java**

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
private static Context context;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}

private class BitmapCache implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache;

    public BitmapCache() {
        mCache = new LruCache<>(20);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mCache.get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        // scaling bitmap for avoiding too much big images
        Bitmap scaled = ImageUtil.getInstance().scaleBitmap(bitmap);
        mCache.put(url, scaled);
    }
}

public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
    if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
        customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
    }
    return customVolleyRequest;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();
    }
    return requestQueue;
}

 public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return imageLoader;
 }

}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
 class ProductMainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageRecord> {
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private String jsonObject;

    ProductMainAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.grid_item);
        mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getContext()).getImageLoader();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_gridview);
            holder.priceTagImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTag_IV);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            holder.priceTagRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTag_RL);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ImageRecord imageRecord = getItem(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(imageRecord != null ? imageRecord.getUrl() : null, mImageLoader);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openProductDetail(position);
            }
        });
        holder.textView.setText(imageRecord != null ? imageRecord.getTitle() : null);
        holder.priceTagRL.setRotation(0);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        ImageView priceTagImage;
        NetworkImageView imageView;
        RelativeLayout priceTagRL;
    }

    private void openProductDetail(int position) {
        try {
            ImageRecord imr = getItem(position);
            String productID = imr != null ? imr.getId() : "0";
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("pid", productID);
             getContext().startActivity(intent);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("openProductDetail", "exception", e);
        }
    }
```

I wonder what I am missing/ doing wrong in the provided implementation. It has been taking almost 2-3 months, I could not able to handle that issue. Has anyone ever faced a similar situation? Any suggestion or comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195367/android-gridview-opens-the-same-entry-the-first-clicked-one-in-subsequent-cli

Comment: Question is why don't you obtain data in ProductDetailActivity itself ... and from gridview start the new activity only

Comment: @Selvin, I need to pass the clicked item `id` to the `ProductDetailActivity`, where I am using this `id` for URL call to get all information such as `product price, product images, product location, seller name and seller city`... In other words, I am also doing network operation in the `ProductDetailActivity` as well.

Comment: @Selvin, I have added the missing code, and refined the adapter class. I would be glad if you have a chance to look at it.

Comment: Is it possible in `openProductDetail` you're getting a null ImageRecord and keep passing through "0" as the id? Is "0" mapped to a product and is it the one your user kept seeing?

Comment: @Dom, no there is no item id equals to 0.

Comment: Could you post the adapter code?

Comment: @AustinHanson, I have added the adapter as well. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you so much in advance. I have also added screenshots.

Comment: @Selvin, I have added more detail information and also put bounty (+50)

Comment: Inside `onItemClick` pls try using `Toast` right before `openProductDetail(position);` to display the position value. Or  try using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`...before `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @BNK, `onItemClick` returns the right position. `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` are also tested but no luck.

Comment: @BNK, I have tested application with two different Internet providers : `3G` and `WIFI`. Application works perfectly fine with `WIFI` but when I switched to `3G` then it starts giving the same issue.

Comment: Does Volley do any sort of caching where if there is no internet connection it returns the last result?

Comment: @AustinHanson, here is the scenario that I have tested. I started with `3g` and clicked on the first item and see the item detail, it is perfectly fine. and go back to main. then click on the second item, then it still shows me the first item in the `DetailActivity` that I clicked initially. Then I switched to `wifi` when app is open, no matter what I click it shows me the first item that I clicked initially. But when I delete the app and reinstall it and get wifi access only, app works perfectly fine.

Comment: @AustinHanson, I have added `Volley` class into the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270574/app-works-on-wifi-but-not-on-3g

Comment: The code you posted in that question is different - you don't use gridView.setOnItemClickListener() and instead set one on the viewHolder. Are you actually doing both? You check for a network connection in the viewHolder openProductDetail but not in the gridView - this maybe the reason why?

Comment: @AustinHanson, does it really matter to get clicked item position in the `adapter` vs `gridview` ? just in case, I have implemented in that way as well, but I get the same position. I have tested both version with `3G`, both did not work... However both works with `Wifi` connection.

Comment: But you weren't using *both* at the same time, right? That was my concern, if you were using both... The position should be reported correctly. If you can reproduce consistently, set a breakpoint at the code that creates the intent and in onCreate of the detail activity and check the values of the extra.

Comment: @AustinHanson, no I am not using both at the same time. By the way, I have tested application on 4G in adddition to WIFI, it works.. but 3G does not.

Comment: have you tried to debug this? what is a point of wrong direction ? does it pass correct id to DetailActivity ? does it call the correct url ? does it receive correct data ? does data be parsed correct ?

Comment: Are you sure your 3G ISP is returning the HTTP you expect, not a cached or modified version of what you expected from the server? Have you tried other devices on other 3G networks? Or does the HTTP response have headers that tell the client to cache the request and it is incorrect so it is caching different requests under the same key?

Answer (score 2):

You could just kill the activities with finish(); when the other one loads.

Comment: I am finishing activities but that is not the issue.

Comment: Ok, I am just looking over your code. According to what you posted here, you aren't finishing the activities. If you want to, you should call finish() after every startActivity.

Comment: How is it related with `pid` which I am sending from main to detail activity?

Comment: You can see in the `OnPause` method, I call `finish();`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. In my case in `onClick` method the position was not correct.
Then I used to set the position as a tag to the specific view which has `OnClickListener` set and my problem solved.
It may be due to the position is declared as `final`. So remove the final keyword and try like this.

```
holder.imageView.setImageUrl(imageRecord != null ? imageRecord.getUrl() : null, mImageLoader);
holder.imageView.setTag(position);
holder.priceTagRL.setRotation(0);
```

And in `onClick` method

```
openProductDetail((int)view.getTag());
```

Comment: If the position is incorrect, why does it get right position when I use wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below link can be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682366/2798289 (3G connection might actually be slow that you to have increase the threshold of timeout)

Also, there is a chance the position reference in the adapter can come wrong in some edge case (irrespective of your actual issue). You can try the below alternative method..

Use `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            //do your logic based on the position
        }
    });
```

Note: In case if GridView is not able to observe the item click event, you have to set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the child root view under gridview. This might happen basically because the GridView items should not be clickable by itself as it will observe the click event.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I initially implemented and tested this one, but did not work